# Black background on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, ios

While I initially liked the ability to set custom backgrounds on my iPhone 4, I've come to find that I'm starting to miss the simple black background I had on my iPhone 3G. How can I set my background back to black?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a black image in your favorite image editor (even Paint will do if you're on Windows), save it as a jpeg, and e-mail or sync it to the phone. Then set that image as the background.

Since you're making it all black, I doubt the resolution is going to matter much, but you can always use 960 x 640 to use the iPhone 4's standard resolution.

**Edit** to add a black image that works:

[image]

Comment: Hm, that seems like a bit of a hack, but I guess it could work. So there's no setting to get it back? Incidentally, do you happen to have a black image I could use for this?

Comment: @Airplane Mode: Sorry, that's the only way I know of that works. Have added a black image for you.

Comment: +1 for the artistic skill in the included background image :)

Comment: @torbengb - Ha, thanks! Unfortunately, that's the limit of my artistic skill...;-)